# Java makefile that creates a folder for the classes

Tags: java, makefile

I'm trying without any success to create a java makefile that compiles the java source codes to classes which go in a specific folder. So far, I managed to get the classes but I am really having trouble understanding how to create a folder and place the classes in there.

Here's my code so far:

```
JC = javac
JVM = java
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) *.java

default: .java.class

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

I followed a lot of tutorials and still can't figure it out. Basically I have my .java files in my folder. When I run `make`, I would like the classes to go in `/bin` folder and if it doesn't exist it gets created

Comment: I realise I'm not answering your specific question, but makefiles aren't a 'normal' means of building Java solutions. If you use Maven (for example) it's a much more idiomatic solution, supporting building, mgmt of 3rd party libraries, testing and packaging (Gradle is another option, as is the more basic Ant)

Comment: @BrianAgnew I completely understand your point. It's for an assignment and this thing is so unnecessary but they want it to give marks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want to do with suffix rules.  You'll have to use [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) if you want the output to be placed in a different directory than the source.  Pattern rules are a feature of GNU make so hopefully you're using that (you don't say).

Plus, the way you're using suffix rules is not right: you don't declare the suffix rule itself as a prerequisite.  You declare the actual files you want to build as prerequisites.

Also, make cannot do this by itself: you have to tell your compiler where to put the output.  I'm not a Java person so I can't help you with that.  Check your manual.

Your recipe builds all the .java files with a single invocation, which is not really how make works: make wants to translate a single source file (plus possibly other header files etc.) into a single output file.

Replace your suffix rule:

```
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
        $(JC) *.java
```

with a pattern rule:

```
$(OUT)/%.class : %.java
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(JC) -o $@ $<
```

(I have no idea if `-o` is right for `javac`: as I said you'll have to consult your Java manual).  You don't need to declare `.SUFFIXES` when you use pattern rules.

Then, declare your default target to depend on the output files you want to be generated:

```
classfiles := $(wildcard *.class)

default: $(classfiles:%.class=$(OUT)/%.java)
```